# CsvHelper - How to map by index the whole row to a model member

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm working on a C# windows service that reads in a csv file into a `List<model>` using CsvHelper along with it's class map by index functionality.  I would like to store the original raw data row in each model.

I've tried using `Map(m => m.Row).Index(-1);` but that did not work.  I also tried `ConvertUsing`, but I get a message that MemberMap does not contain a definition for 'ConvertUsing'.

The `RegisterClassMap` and `csv.GetRecords` functionality is doing a bulk read that doesn't give me an opportunity to capture the original raw data row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I need to create an email with the status (sending the data to a micro service) and the original raw data two, and would love to store it while CsvHelper is reading the file.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("Id,Name\r\n");
    s.Append("1,one\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

private class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RawRow { get; set; }
}

private class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.RawRow).Convert(args => args.Row.Parser.RawRecord);
    }
}
```

`.Dump()` is a [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net) method.